# Is it unusual for mangas to be in colour?

Tags: manga-production, manga-history

I have been reading some mangas lately and they seem to be commonly done in black and white rather than colour. Also, according to the community at other websites such as comicvine.com, they are usually not in colour.

I came across this when I was wondering if a comic book would be an equivalent to a manga and it made me wonder whether it would be unusual for a manga to be done in colour.

Comment: Related Question: [why do manwha more oftenly have colored pages then manga](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7414/why-do-manwha-more-oftenly-have-colored-pages-then-manga)